# Name of a book about a world where people have animal familiars, the MC sets out to discover the origins of the original soul bond with the familiars

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, animals

I think it was a book series but only read one book. It was about this guy setting out of a journey to discover why his people form soul bonds with animals or something like that. He had a cat - it's either purple or blue.

It isn't Golden Compass, I know the whole soul thing sounds like Golden Compass but that was their actual soul but in this book it's more like a soul contract or something.

I read it about 10 years ago and I hadn't even read the entire thing so I'm unsure what the entire book is about, I only remember the MC had a cat (it may have been much bigger than a normal cat and it could speak to the MC, but I'm not sure if it was a form of telepathy or verbally) The cover was of the MC approaching a forest or something and in the foreground was the cat which I think was blue.

I'm not sure if I'm remembering this right but I think that the main character's people may not have originated from the planet, they came to the planet where they first met these sentient animals and came to form a bond with the animals, each person ended up forming a bond over time with one of the animals, I think that's the origins the MC found after he set out on his journey.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember anything about the cover?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for good questions to see if they help you recall any other details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Apart from the daimons of *His Dark Materials*, this reminds me a bit of the bonding between humans and Sphinxian treecats in the *Honor Harrington* series. There are two or three short novels in the same setting, temporally set much earlier than the HH timeline, with Sphinx colonists discovering the bond thing. But it's a minority of the colonists that's involved, not "everyone" by far.

Comment: There seem to be a few similarities to what I remember, the treecat bond with humans but I'm unsure if this is it. The specific book I recall had the MC, which I think was male, going on a journey to figure out how the bond originated. Is there any book in the Honor Harrington series that have this included?

Comment: I can't help you, but your question reminds me quite a bit of Dragonriders of Pern series. Select members bond with dragons, and many people bond with smaller dragons, coincidentally cat-sized, called Fire Lizards. It might be a series that you would enjoy. Good luck in your search!

Comment: I had planned on reading the Dragonriders of Pern series but others series kept popping up, maybe I will one day, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gayle Greeno’s series (*The Ghatti's Tale*) begins with book one [*Finders-Seekers*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/591805.Finders_Seekers) (1993).

The planet was colonized by people from Earth, some of whom bonded with an indigenous species of catlike animals (ghatti) that possessed telepathic abilities. Human and Ghatti are soul bound as you mentioned. The cover of book one shows what appears to be a man seated on a horse with a large cat perched on the front of the saddle. The spine of the book features a large, blueish colored cat. The series consists of five books and is a favorite of mine.

[image: Cover of "Finders-Seekers" showing a person on a horse with a ghatti perched in front]

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is the series. The third book seems to have the part I was remembering, apart from the cover, but that may just be a different edition. Thank you mate

Comment: I’m glad I could help! Nothing more aggravating to an avid reader than coming up blank regarding identifying information for a book you desperately want to find…ask me how I know, lol!